# Write vlookup function with VBA to Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have  difficulties to understand why the following code does not work? I am a missing something?

```
Sub vlookup_test()

Dim class As String
class = "tmp_1" 

Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=vlookup(" & class & ",'Sheet1'!A:B,2,FALSE)"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is `tmp_1` the name of a range, or a literal text value? If it's the latter, it needs to be in quotes: `Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=vlookup(""" & class & """,'Sheet1'!A:B,2,FALSE)"`

Comment: It is a text! And thank you, it's working perfectly! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have modify the code in order to give a more clear view of the sub.

```
Sub vlookup_test()

    Dim class As String
    Dim rngSearch As Range
    class = "tmp_1"

    'Create a with statement for the worksheet of your interest
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Set the range to search in
        Set rngSearch = .Range("C:D")
        'Check if value found
        If IsError(Application.VLookup(class, rngSearch, 2, False)) = False Then
            'Found
            .Cells(1, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(class, rngSearch, 2, False)
        Else
            'Not found
            .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Not Found"
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

This will fix the existing code:

`Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""" & class & """,'Sheet1'!A:B,2,FALSE)"`